# facebook pixel configurable products

Tags: magento2, facebook, ecommerce-tracking

No matter what facebook pixel code we add or no matter what extension we add the fb pixel will not pull through the correct data on the configurable products [image: incorrect price and product name]

we have tried many extensions and fb pixels but we always get the price from the cheapest child product and only get parent sku not the child sku

Comment: Can you show what your using code wise so can get a better understanding

Comment: <script>
      fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
    content_name: 'The Otty Mattress',
    content_category: 'Uk Store',
    content_ids: ['The Otty Mattress'],
    content_type: 'product',
    value: 349.99,
    currency: 'GBP'
   });
     </script>

we have tried 3 different extensions with this exact same result 

https://www.otty.com/

Comment: as you will see if you follow the link i have just provided when you add variable product to cart the add to cart pixel doesnt show correct data

Comment: What php variable are you using to get the final price

Comment: sorry for not getting back to you we was trying different extensions now the situation is even worse, the addtocart doesnt fire when you addtocart and get redirected to cart page but if you press home but addtocart appears so seems like something very odd is happening, this question may possibly get placed on hold because im not sure wether its facebook or magento relate just yet

Comment: removing the automatic redirect when adding product to cart has solved the pixel firing issue but i really dont like this extra step of customers having to get to cart now